# Backbone + kendoGrid, PUT not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, kendo-ui

I'm trying to integrate kendoGrid on a Backbone View, this is my view code:

```
App.Views.UsersManager = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'section',
  id: 'users-manager',
  className: 'tile',
  template: Handlebars.compile($('#profile-usersManager-template').html()),
  render: function () {
    console.log('usersManager.render -> collection', this.collection);
    var self = this;
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
        read: {
          url: '/users',
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json'
        },
        update: {
          url: '/users',
          type: 'PUT',
          dataType: 'json'
        }
      },
      schema: {
        data: 'data'
      },
      batch: true
    });
    this.$('table.users-manager').kendoGrid({
      scrollable: false,
      sortable: true,
      dataSource: dataSource,
      toolbar: ["save"],
      editable: true,
      navigatable: true,
      // filterable: true,
    });
    return this;
  }
});
```

The view render correctly, and the kendoGrid correctly GET my users data from my SlimPHP framework, but when i try to modify an element of the grid and hit the "Save Changes" button provided by "toolbar: ["save"]", nothing happens, even on my firebug console... there's no server communication at all.

I'm new on kendo (and Backbone also) development, maybe i'm failing something on the syntax? :stuck:

**Update after Atanas Korchev answer**
this is my DataSource updated:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: '/users',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json'
    },
    update: {
      url: '/users',
      type: 'PUT',
      dataType: 'json'
    }
  },
  schema: {
    data: 'data',
    model: {
      id: 'id',
      fields: {
        email: {},
        name: {},
        surname: {},
        rank: {},
        type: {}
      }
    }
  },
  batch: true
});
```

That not solve my issue, i wanna notice that my php code look like that actually:

```
$app->put('/users', function () use ($app, $db) {
  exit('put ok');
});
```

Just to see if the client/server communication works... I know it will be an error, but I can't see any firebug error too, like the "Save Changes" button has no event... (I will try the **Dennis Rongo** suggestion.. but I dont think is the solution...)

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Where is your collection and model definition?

Comment: There's no model/collection definition actually, I assume I had to use the kendo dataSource...

Comment: I see. Not so familiar with KendoUI Grid but after reading about it, I'm also not seeing where you're triggering the `save` such as `this.kendoGrid.bind('save', save);`.

Answer (score 1):

Try describing your model in the DataSource [settings](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schemamodel-objectkendodatamodel):

```
schema: {
   data: 'data',
   model: {
      id: "MyId"      
   }
}
```

You need to at least specify the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the data: 'data' from the schema object, there's the link [kendoGrid batch editing](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html)!